# How to connect raspberrypi to Ad-Hoc

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, adhoc

I am trying to have a RaspberryPi (running Raspbian) join an Ad-Hoc network (no password) hosted by a desktop computer with a wireless card running Debian 7. I was able to connect to the Ad-Hoc network with a laptop running Windows 7 and it successfully was given the IP 10.42.0.69, however, all of my attempts at connecting from the RaspberryPi have failed.

The RaspberryPi is using the Edimax Wifi USB, and I already tried to request a static IP for the Ad-Hoc network with the following settings in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.42.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
    wireless-essid TESTING
```

All that I did to configure the wifi network on the desktop is to use "Create New Wireless Network" in the panel's network manager. Below is the output of ifconfig on the Debian 7 desktop:

```
wlan0     
    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:50:d5:d6:61  
    inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::211:50ff:fed5:d661/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:5347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:8698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:884808 (864.0 KiB)  TX bytes:4728097 (4.5 MiB)
```

And here is iwconfig:

```
wlan0 
    IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"TESTING"  
    Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: C6:D7:1D:CB:74:CD   
    Tx-Power=20 dBm   
    Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
    Encryption key:off
    Power Management:off
```

What do I need in /etc/network/interfaces on the RPi to get it to connect?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: The solution to this problem is to also define the gateway and key:

```
gateway as 10.41.0.1
wireless-key 01234567890
```

Then install isc-dhcp-server. Then, using the configuration of the dhcpd.conf, you can select a simple network domain like the following:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 10.42.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.42.0.0.2 10.42.0.0.3;
}
```

Now restart the device and the /etc/network/interfaces will be loaded properly and the network will be served.